# Provide Run name to Terraform Cloud execution using CLI

Tags: terraform, hashicorp, terraform-cloud

I am looking for an option from Terraform CLI to provide a run name in terraform Cloud. Ideally that happens if I execute it with Terraform API driven approach.

Here you can see, you can add Reason for Starting a run , Is there an option present to provide the same in CLI?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @MarkoE I am executing Terraform CLI to terraform cloud execution, however in API I get an option to provide run reason, I am looking if terraform CLI also has kind of similar option.

Comment: Terraform CLI does not set the API property corresponding to that "reason" box when it starts a remote run, so there is no way to customize that message when using CLI-driven runs.